# php - regex to match div tags

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I'm using regex to match specific div's in a page and replace them with a custom formatted one. I can't use domdocument as often the pages we process are mal-formed and after running it through domdocument, the pages are reformatted and don't display the same.

I'm currently using the following which works perfectly:

```
preg_match('#(\<div id=[\'|"]'.$key.'[\'|"](.*?)\>)(.*?)\<\/div\>#s', $contents, $response);
```

To match div tags such as:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="test" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
etc...
```

The problem I'm encountering is tags where the id is after the style or class, example:

```
<div class="test" id="test"></div>
```

If I run the following, the regex seems to become greedy and matches a ton of html before the div tag, so I'm not sure how to fix this:

```
preg_match('#(\<div(.*?)id=[\'|"]'.$key.'[\'|"](.*?)\>)(.*?)\<\/div\>#s', $contents, $response);
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: take a look at this, might be somewhat helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4231382/471272).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Ungreedy modifer (`U`), and also - do not use `.*`, but `[^>]*` (which means anything that is not > as > is the end of the tag and you are searching withing the tag). You don't need to escape / when this is not your delimiter (you are using # as delimiter)

```
preg_match('#(<div[^>]*id=[\'|"]'.$key.'[\'|"][^>]*>)(.*)</div>#isU', $contents, $response);
```

Comment: +1 `[^>]*` is super valuable when Regex parsing HTML.

Comment: I <3 stack overflow, thanks a ton for the answer. I'll accept it when the time delay is over in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex for HTML parsing, there are DOM parsers out there, like PHP DOM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Right, but to use them, you need a valid dom, which can mean tidy first, then implementing the dom object, and that can be a lot of overhead. Sometimes, especially when you're looking for specific bits of information, it doesn't make sense to go through the whole ritual of Dom parsing, when you can write a simple regular expression in two lines of code.

Comment: There's no need to be afraid of this stuff. It's only a chainsaw.